# Web service test tools

Tags: database, web-services, testing

What test tools can issues parallel request to testing web service (web application) and check data base state of this app on same time?

Comment: please elaborate your question. Do you want to do load testing or check db status after web ervice request?

Comment: Not load testing. I want functional testing tool to check db state at any time of test execution.

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter can do so using either:

- webservice sampler
- regular http sampler

Regards

Philippe M.